# Ajax Value Not Transmitting To PHP

Tags: php, ajax, variables, scope, echo

I have this Star Rating system right. When you click on a star it should pass a value into the function. Then using AJAX it posts it to an external PHP file. The only problem is that when it gets to the PHP file it comes as null or no value.

I will try to echo the $_POST['vote'] variable in an alert box using AJAX and it is blank so it doesn't come back as "NULL" or "0" it's just nothing. I'm not sure where I'm losing the value because I can track it all the way to the send() function. Anyone see a problem?

**HTML:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{margin: 10px auto;width: 500px;height: 300px;background-color: gray;}
    #starContainer{padding-top:20px;margin:0 auto;width:150px;}
    .box{height:28px;width:30px;float:left;position:relative;z-index:5;cursor:pointer;}
    .star{background-image:url('emptyStar.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;}
    .starHover{background-image:url('goldStar.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;}
    #voteBar{float:left;height:28px;background-color:#dbd923;position:relative;top:-28px;z-index:1;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('starHover');
        },
        // Handles the mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('starHover'); 
        }
    );
});

    function Cast(vote)
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "process.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send('vote=' + vote);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <center>
        <div id="starContainer">
            <div class="box star" onclick="Cast(1)"></div>
            <div class="box star" onclick="Cast(2)"></div>
            <div class="box star" onclick="Cast(3)"></div>
            <div class="box star" onclick="Cast(4)"></div>
            <div class="box star" onclick="Cast(5)"></div>
            <div id="voteBar"></div>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$vote = $_POST['vote'];

$totalVoteValue = 0;
$amtVotes = 1;

$width = (($totalVoteValue + (($vote - $totalVoteValue) / $amtVotes)) / 5) * 150;

echo $width;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

adding this may help (before send after open)

Comment: I tried that then I thought that line of code was the problem so I took it out.

Comment: That's indeed the shortest answer to the question.

Comment: I don't understand it. I had the same exact thing in my original script with Double Quotes instead of single, but I plug this in and it works. It should be all the same since their strings anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You are already using jquery (a very very very old version if i may say..), why not use it's built in ajax handler?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post('process.php', {vote: vote}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Comment: I was using javascript for it because I just started AJAX not too long ago, I understand the javascript version better than the JQuery one. I'll look into that though.

Comment: "better"? no it's not, if you're using jQuery might as well go all the way, ensure cross-browser compat and such, anyway good luck.